# Can't generate DDL creation script with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to generate DDL creation script with Spring Boot, and found somewhere that this configuration is supposed to do it:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            create-source: metadata
            scripts:
              action: create
              create-target: create.sql
```

However, when I compile and start the code, nothing happens. There's no new files generated. These are the versions that I currently use:

```
spring-boot: 1.5.16.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 1.5.16.RELEASE

hibernate-jpa-2.1

Hibernate-java8: 5.0.12
```

Comment: Hi @Zed, the same configuration works fine on Spring Boot v2.1.8.RELEASE and creates the *sql* file in **root folder**. Have you checked root folder or might be some different property name will be there for 1.5.16 as we have for multipart size

Comment: do you manually import the two Hibernate specific dependencies? Can you remove them and let Spring Boot manage the Hibernate specific versions?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the datasource configuration?

```
spring:
  datasource:
  ....
```

You may find further useful info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-data-access)

Comment: Yeah, I removed it, thought it's not relevant. Database connection work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Up to *JPA 2.1* you needed to use the vendor-specific configuration parameters to define the database setup in the `persistence.xml` file. Starting from version *2.1* there is also a standard way to do the following. You might need to update `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 1.5.16.RELEASE` to `2.1 or later versions`

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action //used here
javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source //used here
javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source
javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target //used here
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target
javax.persistence.database-product-name
javax.persistence.database-major-version
javax.persistence.database-minor-version
javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source
javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source
javax.persistence.schema-generation.connection
javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source
```

[JPA 2.1 Overview](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-overview/)